# One-parameter family of cubics; smallest parameter value guaranteeing unique real root?

Tags: functions

[image]

why is the case that only if p is larger than the P that satisfies the condition that f(x) only has two roots, the function will have only one root?

Comment: Hint: could you try to answer the symmetric question: "Compute the biggest value $p$ such as $\forall q < p$, the polynomial $x^3+x^2+qx+9$ has exactly one real root?

Comment: As the influence of changes of p can't be show straightly in the graph of the function, I can't understand why when p is larger than -39/4, the function will only have one root rather than 3 roots.

Comment: Do you understand why, if $q=-39/4$, the polynomial has a root at $x=-4$ and a double root at $x=3/2$? Can you visualize what the graph must look like, for that value of $q$? Then can you see that if you increase $q$ you increase the value of the polynomial near that double root, so there is no longer a root there, so there's only one real root?

Comment: Why increase? I have draw the graph...

Comment: If that question is directed to me, Samara, you have to write @Gerry in order to be sure I'm notified. Anyway, since $x$ is positive near the double root, when you increase $q$, you increase $qx$, and so you increase the value of the polynomial.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, I understand. So not all functions have this quality. Thanks a lot.